# TNetHttpClient Custom TimeOut

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

First of all I'm very excited that Embarcadero/Idera finally decided to include a build-in component for HTTP/S communication!

And I know that this sounds like a silly question (and maybe it is) ... but I'm having problems finding the property (or something) to set a custom TimeOut (response, receive, ...).

Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: I don't think that the TNetHttpClient has a timeout property or method (looking at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient)

Comment: But ... why? :) I've even tried it with classic InternetSetOption with no success. `InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, @LConnectTimeoutMS, Sizeof(LConnectTimeoutMS));`

Comment: I've got no idea brother. BTW: I was commenting from a Firemonkey perspective and it looks like your doing windows stuff so maybe just use indy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858551/delphi-xe2-indy-10-multithread-ping

Comment: It's like that - We've been using Indy but I don't like the external DLLs for HTTPS. So, when I found out that this is now "solved" with a native Delphi component I was excited ... But my luck ran out on me very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too had a similar problem, though I only needed to be able to set a custom value for the connection timeout. I had to copy and modify two RTL files to accomplish this. First my modifications to the System.Net.Http.Client.pas file:

```
THTTPClient = class(TURLClient)
...
private
  FConnectTimeout: Integer; // <---- add this line
...
public
  property ConnectTimeout: Integer read FConnectTimeout write FConnectTimeout; // <---- add this line
```

Here are my modifications to the System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas file:

```
procedure TWinHTTPRequest.DoPrepare;
var // <---- add this line
  LConnectTimeout: integer; // <---- add this line
begin
  inherited;
  SetWinProxySettings;

  LConnectTimeout := THTTPClient(FClient).ConnectTimeout; // <---- add this line
  WinHttpSetOption(FWRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, @LConnectTimeout, sizeof(LConnectTimeout)); // <---- add this line
end;
```

These modifications are for the Delphi 10 Seattle RTL files. Hope this helps!

Comment: Works like a charm. I've added two more lines (WINHTTP_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT and WINHTTP_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT). Thank you @unixguru65!

Comment: Note that this change will make the class platform-dependent, because WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT etc. are not available on Android / iOS / OSX